# How to solve "no module named spacy error"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, nlp, spacy

I know this question asked for couple of times and there are some solutions in the stackoverflow but even though i tried them all I couldn't fix the problem.

Here are the lines that I try to run from my terminal:

1)pip install -U pip setuptools wheel

2)pip install -U spacy

3)python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm

First two lines work well but at the last one I get "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named spacy" error.

I see an answer like below but I didn't get how can I navigate to the directory to my 'normal' version of Python.

"It is possible that the version of Python at /usr/bin/python is not the one that has spacy installed. If so, navigating to the directory where your 'normal' version of Python is before running".

Note: I tried the following commands to check if it's a version related issue. First of all, when I say `python --version`, it returns 2.7, even though I have a more recent version. When I researched, I found out that this is a case of linux, that I have to type `python3 --version` to see the new version.
However, if I use the `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm` command in the terminal with python or python3, I get the same result.
Attached is the image of the error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHHzY.png)

Comment: Have you tried using `python -m pip` instead of pip? That way it should use the same python version you use later

Comment: did you try ```which python``` to check the path to the Python executable

Comment: You are, of course, fully aware that support for Python 2.7 ended three years ago?

Comment: yes of course. another project I was working on required me to use the old version.

Comment: @AsiriHewage yes i did and it returns me /usr/bin/python.